# How to return single object from Reactive REST API in Kotlin Coroutine style

Tags: spring, kotlin, reactive-programming, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to convert a REST service from the Spring 5 Reactive style to an async Kotlin Coroutine style.

I followed several different guides/tutorials on how this should work but I must be doing something wrong.

I get a compile error trying to turn a single object into a Flow, whereas the guides I'm following dont seem to do this at all.

Any pointers or otherwise very appreciated!

---

Router:

```
   @Bean
    fun mainRouter(handler: EobHandler) = coRouter {
        GET("/search", handler::search)
        GET("/get", handler::get)
    }
```

Handler:

```
    suspend fun search(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse {
        val eobList = service.search()
        return ServerResponse.ok().bodyAndAwait(eobList)
    }

    suspend fun get(request: ServerRequest): ServerResponse 
        val eob = service.get()
        return ServerResponse.ok().bodyAndAwait(eob); // compile error about bodyAndAwait expecting a Flow<T>
    }
```

Service:

```
    override fun search(): Flow<EOB> {
        return listOf(EOB()).asFlow()
    }

    //
    override suspend fun get(): EOB? {
       return EOB()
    }
```

If curious, here are some of the guides I've based my code on:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-kotlin-coroutines

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/languages.html#how-reactive-translates-to-coroutines

https://medium.com/@hantsy/using-kotlin-coroutines-with-spring-d2784a300bda

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to compile by changing

```
return ServerResponse.ok().bodyAndAwait(eob);
```

to

```
return eob?.let { ServerResponse.ok().bodyValueAndAwait(it) } ?: ServerResponse.notFound().buildAndAwait()
```

guess it's something to do with type-safety of Kotlin - I was not returning a nullable object I think